# Get Value dynamically from XML and put in to JSON array and then in String Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml

I am trying to convert the below XML to a JSON array, and then to a String array:

```
<property name="productIcon">
  <jsonproperty key="productImage"><![CDATA[AAAAA - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.]]></jsonproperty>
  <jsonproperty key="produtIconName"><![CDATA[BBBBB - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.]]></jsonproperty>
  <jsonproperty key="produtIconDesc"><![CDATA[CCCCC - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry]]></jsonproperty>

  <jsonproperty key="productImage"><![CDATA[11111 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.]]></jsonproperty>
  <jsonproperty key="produtIconName"><![CDATA[22222 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.]]></jsonproperty>
  <jsonproperty key="produtIconDesc"><![CDATA[33333 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry]]></jsonproperty>
</property>
```

This is the final output I'm trying to achieve:

```
[
{"productImage":" AAAAA - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry ",
"produtIconName":" BBBBB - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry ",
"produtIconDesc":" CCCCC - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry "}”,
{"productImage":" 11111 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry ",
"produtIconName":" 22222 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry ",
"produtIconDesc":" 33333 - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry "}”
}]
```

This is what I tried:

```
if(node.getNodeName().equals("key")) {
    JSONObject[] test = new JSONObject();
    test.push(node.getNodeValue(),tempNode.getTextContent());
    System.out.println("JSON : " + jsonArray);
}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I get to the desired result?